# How can I generate UTF8 table using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate version: 4.3.8.Final

In web.xml i have:
`

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />

        <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>`
```

When I run app, hibernate generate all table in: latin1_swedish_ci

I read a lot of pages on google, but nothing help me.

How can I generate utf8 table using hibernate? **IT IS POSSIBLE?**

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect implementation you'll find this :

```
package org.hibernate.dialect;

/**
 * @author Gavin King, Scott Marlow
 */
public class MySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " ENGINE=InnoDB";
    }

    public boolean hasSelfReferentialForeignKeyBug() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

So you can see in *getTableTypeString* the return value, what you can do is extends the **MySQLDialect** class and override *getTableTypeString* method to return

> "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

Otherwise (you can try a lazy solution)  try with adding `UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8` at the end of your database connection url